# AAPT.exe crashes, when trying to support APIs older than 12

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt

What might be the probable cause for the "AAPT.exe has stopped working" error, when it only appears after changing minSdkVersion to something lower than 12?

I had started developing an application, which was targeting API 18 and I decided to support older versions, too. There is nothing useful to update in the Android SDK Manager nor in the Eclipse-plugins. Eclipse isn't giving me any hints about what might be wrong. Naturally, I have tried cleaning the project, but it always ends in showing that error.

Comment: Where do you see this error? If it is in the Eclipse Console, are there any lines of interest immediately preceding it? Have you tried a command-line build, using Ant or Gradle, to see if you get a more informative message?

Comment: It is Microsoft Windows, which throws such an error telling that the executable in question has stopped working. I tried the brutal force -technique and started deleting class-files and removing parts of xml-files until I didn't get the error anymore. It seems that the problem might be related to the Google Maps API and support libraries. Will do further investigation.

Comment: Problem was related to SearchView widget's xml-file. Strange thing is that even when I've included the support library (v7), minSdkVersion is 10 and targetSdkVersion is 18, the error will appear, if the following part is included in the xml-file: _android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"_ . I guess I could try importing Support Library Project, but my hopes aren't very high.

Comment: `android:actionViewClass` will not be used on API Level 10 and below, as that attribute did not exist then. You need to use your own custom namespace: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Comment: You are correct, but now the problem is that I can't get action view from the Java-code using the getActionView-method and thus SearchView will be null (only when using support libraries' methods and setting minSdkVersion to 10). There already seems to be some questions and answers available related to that matter.